# XCode project doesn't auto-load on mac start after renaming it

Tags: xcode

I recently renamed my XCode-project. It still runs without issue. The problem arises when I restart the computer, and XCode auto-reopens the same project, but with the name in red. I need to close it and re-open it manually to be able to use it again at that point.

[image: image of the xcode project error]

Do you know any steps to remediate this issue? :)

Comment: How did you do this renaming?

Comment: @matt I don't think refactoring works at that level, so I went through all instances of the old name and manually changed it, incl. entries in the build-settings, and the names of the build shemes. I wonder if there is a hidden reference somewhere to the old name still that is being auto-loaded on startup.

Comment: Ok so that was your mistake. There is a correct way to rename a project and that was not it. Your project is now hosed, and I cannot tell you how to fix it. It would be better to migrate into a new project. Or use Git to roll back and do this correctly (assuming you committed just before the rename).

Comment: @matt Thanks for the confirmation! Might set up a new one then, the rename did happen weeks ago. What is the correct way to do this? :)

Comment: First of all, you don't usually need to rename a project, as the name is not user-facing. (To change the app name, change the display bundle name.) But if you do want to rename it, select the name as shown at the top of the project navigator, hit Return to make it editable, change it, and hit Return. Everything will be renamed appropriately (almost).

Comment: @matt, cool, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more experimentation. You can go wild renaming things, but once the main folder everything is in is renamed the auto-loading will fail. I created a new project with the correct naming and copied everything over :)